# Finish php script before executing

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, stored-procedures

I'm making a multiplayer smartphone game where I have PHP as my backend. When a player makes a move info is send to my PHP script which executes the script, and in the end sends some info back to the smartphone. When alot of players a plying atr the same time (Now I have a workload of 2-4 requests each msecond) the response time is a bit long... I have about 3-4 different SELECT queries and 4-5 UPDATE/INSERT queries in my script.

I have been looking into Stored Procedures and are thinking of maybe using AJAX but not sure. What I want to accomplish is to get the response time down on the smartphone by sending the data back as soon as possible in the script and then execute the rest afterwards!

What is the best way to approach this?

Thanks for all your advice in advance ;-)

Comment: "execute the rest afterwards" what rest? It might be helpful to know what data is being sent to the server, what is being returned, and what processes you want to execute after the reply has been sent

Comment: This is not the way. You much use sockets and keep the connection active with your players (like old IRC). You can do it with php Sockets extensions. you bind it to any port (other than 80), and listen to requests from your users.

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php#71172

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is a good option because it will not render all the page and do all queries necessary to it.

Then, have you check your queries : are there all indexes ? Have you avoid multiple join ?

so, 2 ways : ajax, reduce the response transfer (using json with very few information is good) and optimize your database

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP as Fast CGI (php-fpm) then you can try return response and continue script in "background".

See function fastcgi_finish_request